# Does head>link[href]'s protocol matter for SSL?

Tags: html, canonical-link, html-head

I recently started loading stylesheets on my webpages using just `//` instead of fighting between `http://` and `https://`. E.g.:

```
<link href="//example.com/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Now I wonder if the same should be done for the `link[rel="canonical"]` tags. E.g.:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="//example.com/index.html" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it, the purpose of `rel="canonical"` is somewhat defeated, as the page now has two names (one for `http:`, one for `https:`).  There's nothing prohibiting it, but it's probably not a good idea.

Pick one or the other and make that the canonical URL.